Architecture advice for Sharepoint 2019 distributed farm with remote site
I don't know if it's possible to achieve this. The idea is to have the Sharepoint farm distributed among 4 servers (or more if needed), 2 of those would remain at the main site and another two could be deployed somewhere else with the help of a RODC. Both sites would access the same portal, BUT if the connection between premises is lost, they should be able to work independently. Am I asking much? At least that is what my boss wants.
On the past I've dealt with this situation with a complete separate farm in a subdomain on the remote emplacement, but now my boss wants to try it within the same farm and domain.
Main problem I see with this approach is that even in the case it "works", after both sites working independently for a time (it may be minutes, hours or days), when the connection is back, one of the sides would lose all the new data they created because of the synchronization on the database (One of the servers in the SQL cluster would "impose" its data over the others, right?).
Thank you very much for your guidance to this lost soul.
